# I have to align an image at the top center of page. I have tried almost every possible thing I know

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```html
<div class="limiter">
  <div class="container-login100">
    <img width="500" height="40" src="../plugins/images/Electronic Document Management System.png">
    <div class="wrap-login100">
      <form class="login100-form validate-form">
        <p style="color: #1A0D44" class="login100-form-title p-b-10">
          Login
        </p>
        </br>
        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Valid email is: a@b.c">
          <input class="input100" type="text" name="email">
          <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Email"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
          <span class="btn-show-pass">
           <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i>
          </span>
          <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass">
          <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Password"></span>
        </div>
        <div style="margin:auto 0; text-align: center;">
          <button type="button" href="">Forgot Password?</button>
        </div>
        </br>
        <div style="margin:auto 0; text-align: center;">
          <button type="button" style=" background-color: #1A0D44; color: white;  padding: 5px 15px;
           border-radius: 60px; border: 1px solid #1A0D44 ;" data-toggle="modal">Login</button>
        </div>


      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Layout]

Comment: Include post content. What image? Your title is not explanation enough for the question

Comment: move the image outside the `container-login100` div

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving it a flex display?

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

We would have to see the rest of your source, but given no other information by setting `.container-login100` to `text-align: center` the image and the contents of the form are centered.

```css
.container-login100 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="limiter">
  <div class="container-login100">
    <img class="center" width="500" height="40" src="../plugins/images/Electronic Document Management System.png">
    <div class="wrap-login100">
      <form class="login100-form validate-form">
        <p style="color: #1A0D44" class="login100-form-title p-b-10">
          Login
        </p>
        </br>
        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Valid email is: a@b.c">
          <input class="input100" type="text" name="email">
          <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Email"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
          <span class="btn-show-pass">
           <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i>
          </span>
          <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass">
          <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Password"></span>
        </div>
        <div style="margin:auto 0; text-align: center;">
          <button type="button" href="">Forgot Password?</button>
        </div>
        </br>
        <div style="margin:auto 0; text-align: center;">
          <button type="button" style=" background-color: #1A0D44; color: white;  padding: 5px 15px;
           border-radius: 60px; border: 1px solid #1A0D44 ;" data-toggle="modal">Login</button>
        </div>


      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class that sets the element to be at the top of its parent(body tag) and center it using know width of element.
You will need to move your image tag to be a child of the body tag.

```
    <style>
        .center-top {
            width: 500px;
            height: 40px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -250px;
        }
    </style>
<body>
    <img
        src="background1.jpg"
        class="center-top"
    >
...
```

Comment: Granted, we don't know much about the rest of the OP's source, but surely there are better ways to achieve this without absolutely positioning the image.

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez You are correct about many ways to achieve the results. This is just one of many ways to complete the task at hand.